# UIHint data annotations slow down the rendering process

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, c#-4.0, data-annotations, telerik-mvc

An MVC 2 C# .NET 4.0 project with Entity Framework contains a view with a user control displaying a [Telerik MVC Extensions](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/razor/grid) grid. The grid uses one table with many fields and displays correctly.

When editing the grid rows, many of the fields need to be drop-down lists.  To create them, I need to annotate the fields in my table with uihint; this uses a editor template that is my drop down list.

There are 13 data annotations for fields for the table object.  Due to these annotations, the grid renders very slowly.  What can be done to optimize this?

Comment: How do you know that the annotations are the cause of this slow rendering?

Comment: I can comment out these annotations and the rendering occurs quickly.  I have also commented out the editor template views with the data annotations left and the render of the grid is very slow.  This leaves me to think it is the annotations.